# Settlers gathering in one spot at night

Tags: fallout-4

So I assigned all of my settlers to their own individual beds, but every time I come back to the settlement all of the towns doors are open and everyone is gathered in my bar instead of being in their beds. But my happiness is still at 82%. How do I get the settlers to use their assigned beds?

I am playing on the PS4.

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect that this is unique to the PS4 version?

Comment: I'm not sure, I have it in ps4. Maybe other platforms have this problem as well

Comment: If you lived in the wasteland and any day could be your last, wouldn't you want to spend more time at the bar than sleeping?

Answer (score 3):

I also witnessed this behaviour and it seems this only happens if you have a bar.

Try to unassign the bar and you will see them going to bed next time. There is also no negative impact if they don't actually use their beds (I don't think they will die from sleep deprivation, because they party every night), as long as they have enough beds.

Comment: I've observed this as well. I built some picnic tables and chairs near the bar, and a decent number of them will sit down. Doesn't looks as weird that way.

Answer (score 0):

Some people have had issues with building beds in custom structures and then the npcs don't enter the prefabs and sleep but they don't need the sleep essentially.

Or all of your settlers are Synths :O. Because synths don't need sleep.

Comment: I've found that sometimes settlers can't pathfind into the structure.  To check, select a settler and direct them to enter the building.  If they can't get in, you probably need to build steps or build the ground up using shack floor pieces.